# nginx redirection is not working for multiple conditions

Tags: nginx, redirect, configuration-files

I have a nginx configuration where I am defining redirections in below way -

```
rewrite ^/my/(.*)$ /my/ redirect;

rewrite ^/help-and-support/(.*)$    /about/help-and-support redirect;

rewrite ^/about/terms-and-conditions/(.*)$ /about/terms-and-conditions redirect;

rewrite ^/about/privacy-policy/(.*)$ /about/privacy-policy redirect;
```

I need to add one more parameter which should be like as below -

`rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.abcd.com/ permanent;`

But when I am adding all above "rewrite" under "location" directive in nginx configuration, it is redirecting every request to www.abcd.com.

I tried to add if condition as well, but they are not working.

My target is that `www.exmaple.com` and any other URL in that domain different to the ones defined above must be redirected to `www.abcd.com`.

Can you please help me out here ?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx does not stop after finding the first match, to stop it from trying to find the next regex that match use the `break` command like this:

```
rewrite ^/my/(.*)$ /my/ break;
```

From the official site: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite

break -- stops processing the current set of ngx_http_rewrite_module directives as with the break directive;

Comment: Hi Sed, thanks for your reply. I added break as well, but after break it is not checking further. Can you please tell me how can I add multiple rewrite within same location ?